# Objective C to Swift Nonnull conversion

Tags: objective-c, swift, function, overriding, non-nullable

Im converting some code from Objective C.

```
-(nonnull NSString*) endpoint {
    return @"LoginRequest";
}
```

The Swift converter produces

```
func endpoint() -> nonnull NSString {
    return "LoginRequest"
}
```

However nonnull is not recognised by swift. This should also be an overrider function.

I believe it should be along the lines of

```
   override func endpoint() -> NSString {
    return "LoginRequest"
    }
```

but it brings up an error.
Method does not override any Method from its superclass. I shouldnt need to remove the override, if I do, it conflicts with the original in the Objective C imported library.

Could you help please?

Comment: Which "Swift converter"?

Comment: https://objectivec2swift.com

Comment: I think its more the override thats the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it

```
override func endpoint() -> String {
  return "LoginRequest"
}
```